# Set Excel file classification through java code

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, classification

I am writing my result set to excel file. Using apache poi jar. I want to set the classification of the excel file to be for internal use only. How do I achieve this using java. Tried multiple methods but none of this is working.

Comment: Do you mean [Apply sensitivity labels to your files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-sensitivity-labels-to-your-files-and-email-2f96e7cd-d5a4-403b-8bd7-4cc636bae0f9)? If so, then this is only possible "for users and organizations whose administrators have set up sensitivity labels." I doubt such organisations will publish these settings here. Thus I doubt you get an answer about this here.